# If the application added new component, will UFT One still work for automation testing?,

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, uft14

If the application added new component, will UFT One still work for automation testing? E.g. moved the child to another parent ,etc.

Couldn't find the answer in the user manual.

Answer (score 0):

This heavily depends on the application and control in question. No general answer can be given. If the partent is not part of the description of the test-object then it should work.

Comment: However, the example given often is compensated by UFT: In the object repository, you (or UFT´s recorder) build a hierarchy of GUI elem placeholders, and those placeholders to not have to reflect the whole hierarchy. Some nodes in the parent-child path can be (and usually are) ommited. As long as the path leads to a unique match, the GUI hierarchy may change without impacting the script, no object repo update required.